# how can I connect these two tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

i need to take only the items from the table "__sobi2_item" that are in the same country of the user.And use this results for the rest of the function Showupdatelisting.  This is my php script:

```
<?php
function showUpdatedListing()
    {

//i found the user country field value...
    global $database;
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $userId = $user->get( 'id' );
    $sql = "SELECT (id) FROM #__community_fields WHERE fieldcode= 'FIELD_COUNTRY'";
    $database->setQuery( $sql );
    $fieldID = $database->loadResult();
    $sql = "SELECT (value) FROM #__community_fields_values WHERE field_id= {$fieldID} && user_id= {$userId}";
    $database->setQuery( $sql );
    $usercountry = $database->loadResult();
// From all the entries i take only ones that have country field like the user has...
    $query = "SELECT `data_txt`, `itemid`, `fieldid` FROM `#__sobi2_fields_data` WHERE (`fieldid` = 6) AND ('data_txt' = {$usercountry})";
    $database->setQuery($query);
    $ResultsArray = $database->loadObjectList();
    
// We need something here like a Query to load only the entries from $ResultsArray... ??
//....instead of this...
    $config =& sobi2Config::getInstance();
        $database = $config->getDb();
        $now = $config->getTimeAndDate();

        $query = "SELECT itemid FROM #__sobi2_item WHERE (published = 1 AND publish_down > '{$now}' OR publish_down = '{$config->nullDate}') ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 0, 30";
        $database->setQuery($query);
        $sids = $database->loadResultArray();
// ......... show update function goes on...

?>
```

### can anyone help me to connect and adjust these query? thanks.

NB:with the last query (4) i need to filter items of the $ResultsArray taking only ones published and ordering them by last_update. i know it is wrong and now there is no connection with the query before. This is how i have tables in mysql:

## _sobi2_fields_data:

itemid
fieldid
data_txt --->(is a description column for each field)

## _sobi2_item:

itemid
published --->( 1 if true, 0 if false )
last_update --->(date of the last update for the item, also equal to the publication   date if there are no changes)

thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for in this question.  Do you want one query that combines the three you are executing?  It looks like you have your query results loaded into your array, so why do you want another Query to load only entries from ResultsArray?

Comment: hi , i made some changes for explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to ask as well. Your last query (number 4) doesn't make sense to me, how is it linked to the above queries?

**[EDIT]** I've linked your 4th table above assuming itemid is the primary key for the items in sobi2_item table and that the value is linked to the sobi_fields_data table via itemid.

```
SELECT 
  cf.id,
  sfd.data_txt,
  sfd.itemid,
  sfd.fieldid
FROM #__community_fields cf
INNER JOIN #__community_fields_values cfv ON cf.id=cfv.field_id
INNER JOIN #__sobi2_fields_data sfd ON cfv.value=sfd.data_txt
INNER JOIN #__sobi2_item si ON sfd.itemid=si.itemid
WHERE cf.fieldcode='FIELD_COUNTRY'
AND cfv.user_id=$userId
AND sfd.fieldid=6
AND si.published=1
AND (si.publish_down > '{$now}' OR si.publish_down = '{$config->nullDate}')
ORDER BY si.last_update DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

Good luck!

Comment: hi martin, thanks for your trick. i will try it, but i need the last query too.. please read the question that i have edited.  thanks.

Comment: First of all thank you again martin for your support. i try your script in loading it like:                       query="SELECT..etc..";                     $database->setQuery($query);          but it gives me this error:"Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuery() on a non-object.."   why?? thanks.
$sids = $database->loadResultArray();

Comment: How are you getting your database object? You can use: $db = JFactory::getDBO(); OR if you are in your model you can use: $db = $this->getDBO();